# ¿Mediante 2 consultas en php como puedo invocar los servicios (json) desde android?

Tags: android, android-volley

Espero me puedan apoyar con esta duda: como llamar desde android 2 consultas (select) en php que muestran los datos en la app. El codigo php es:

```
    ?php $idequivalente = $_REQUEST['idequivalente2']; 
    $idUsuario2 = $_REQUEST['idUsuario2']; 
    $gasto= $_REQUEST['gasto']; 
    $con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=bd", "root", "123"); 
    $res=$con->query("SELECT idequivalente2,alimento,cantidad, unidad, peso, calorias FROM bdapp.tbalimentos where dequivalente2='$idequivalente'"); 
    $res2=$con->query("SELECT * FROM dieta WHERE idUsuario2='$idUsuario2' AND gasto='$gasto'"); 
    $datos=array(); 
    $datos2=array(); 
    $datos['alimentos']=$res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    $datos2['dieta']=$res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    echo json_encode($datos); 
    echo json_encode($datos2); 
    ?>
```

Cuando invoco una consulta si me muestra los datos en la app, ¡¿Como invocar la segunda consulta? El codigo en android es este para una consulta:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) 
    { try { alimentos=new Tbalimentos(); jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i); 
    String calorias = jsonObject.getString("calorias"); 
    System.out.println("valor: " + calorias);
```

DESDE AQUI ME DOY CUENTA QUE ESTA MAL ya que cuando mando a llamar el metodo CargarWS con las dos consulta ya no me muestra nigun dato en la app:

```
    private void cargarWS() {
    String url=("http://192.168.1.34:8000/ServicioWeb/Menu.php?idequivalente2="+Integer.toString(verduras.getId())+"idUsuario2="+4000+"gasto="+1393.32);
    //SE manda la info del JSON a volley para que la lea y procese la info
   jsonOR = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,this,this);//hace el llamado a la url x GET e intenta conectar al WS, en caso d quetodo este correcto  entra al metodo response
    request.add(jsonOR);//se agrega el json object request;permite establecer la  comunicacion con onERROR y onRESPONSE
}
```

si cumple este metodo entra al RESPONSE:

```
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    //----------------------SPRINNER--------------------------
    Tbalimentos alimentos= null;         
    frutasList = new ArrayList<Tbalimentos>();
    JSONArray jsonArray=response.optJSONArray("alimentos");//cogemos cada uno de los elementos dentro de la etiqueta "alimentos"
    JSONObject jsonObject;

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        try {
            alimentos=new Tbalimentos();
            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String calorias = jsonObject.getString("calorias");
            System.out.println("valor: " + calorias);

            alimentos.setIdequivalente2(jsonObject.getInt("idequivalente2"));
            alimentos.setAlimento(jsonObject.getString("alimento"));
            alimentos.setCantidad(jsonObject.optString("cantidad"));
            alimentos.setUnidad(jsonObject.optString("unidad"));
            alimentos.setCalorias(jsonObject.optDouble("calorias",-1));
            frutasList.add(alimentos);
            //System.out.println("lista : " + frutasList.get(i).getIdequivalente2() + "-"+ frutasList.get(i).getAlimento());
            // frutasList.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i));
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    lista = new ArrayList<String>();
    lista.add("Seleccion");
    System.out.println("tamnano Arraglo Frutas: " + frutasList.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < frutasList.size(); i++) {//jsonArray.length()
        lista.add(frutasList.get(i).getIdequivalente2()+frutasList.get(i).getAlimento()+" "+frutasList.get(i).getCantidad()+" "+frutasList.get(i).getUnidad()+" = "+frutasList.get(i).getCalorias()+" kcal");
        System.out.println("lista : " + lista);
    }
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerAdapter=new ArrayAdapter(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lista);
    spdesayuno1.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

    adapter2=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listaview);
    list.setAdapter(adapter2);

    spdesayuno1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
            if(position!=0){ 
                Double calorias=frutasList.get(position-1).getCalorias();
                String gastoT= getArguments()!=null ? getArguments().getString("gasto5"):"SIN DATOS";
                double gastoT2 = Double.parseDouble(gastoT);//
                System.out.println("PARAMETRO: " + gastoT2);
                if(calconsumidas.equals(new Double(0))) {
                    calconsumidas = gastoT2 - calorias;
                }else{
                    calconsumidas = calconsumidas - calorias;
                }                   
                txtobjetivo.setText(gastoT2+"   -   ");
                txtcalorias.setText(calorias+"    =    ");
                txtcalconsumidas.setText(String.format("%.2f",calconsumidas));

                //paso de parametros a colacion desayuno
                args.putString("gasto6",txtcalconsumidas.getText().toString());
                fragment.setArguments(args);

                listaview.add(frutasList.get(position - 1).getAlimento() + " / "+frutasList.get(position - 1).getCantidad()+" "+frutasList.get(position - 1).getUnidad()+" / "+ frutasList.get(position - 1).getCalorias());
                System.out.println("ListView.size(): " + listaview.size());
                adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        }
    });

}
    //De lo contrario entra al ERROR RESPONSE. Donde entra.
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    Log.i("ERROR",error.toString());
    }
```

Comment: No está muy clara tu duda. Sería donde poner el código php que resuelve uno o mas servicios donde cada uno devuelve una respuesta como json? O es una consulta referida a como invocar los servicios desde android?

Comment: Seria donde poner el codigo php si uno o ambas consultas separadas y como llamar desde android esas consultas. Pues con una consulta muestro en la app pero no logro hacer las dos y en la segunda consulta solo necesito un valor y es el que no logro obtener.

Answer (score 0):

Del lado de PHP podés tomar cualquiera de los dos caminos.

Podes tener archivos separados y en ese caso desde el mobile va a apuntar a dos uris diferentes dependiendo del webservice que quieras llamar, por ejemplo:

`www.tusitio.com/wsuno.php` y `www.tusitio.com/wsdos.php`.

La otra alternativa es tener un archivo PHP que resuelve los dos web services dependiendo de un parametro pasado en el request.

El `GET` sería: `www.tusitio.com/webservice.php?ws=wsuno` y en el caso del `POST` la url sería `www.tusitio.com/webservice.php` y el parámetro `ws=uno` iría codificado dentro del cuerpo del request.

En este caso, en el archivo PHP levantarías los parámetros de `$_GET` o `$_POST` y dependiendo del valor del parámetro `ws` ejecutas uno u otro webservice (la consulta a la base de datos y la respuesta json correspondiente)

A título informativo: Existe una forma más en que se puede codificar el webservice, que es en el path del request, por ejemplo `www.misito.com/webservice/wsuno`. Este tipo de request son un poco mas complejos para implementar dado que hay que hacer que el web server dirija todo el tráfico a un archivo php que se encarga de la decodificación y redirección al progrma que finalmente lo termine resolviendo. Para esto por ejemplo en Apache hay que agregar rewrite rules en el archivo `.htaccess`.

**EDICION I**

Supongamos entonces que implementas la solución con GET, tendrias estas dos urls para llamar desde android:

```
www.tusitio.com/webservice.php?ws=wsuno
```

y

```
www.tusitio.com/webservice.php?ws=wsdos
```

Luego en el php:

```
    <?php 
    $wsSolicitado = $_GET['ws'];

    $idequivalente = $_REQUEST['idequivalente2']; 
    $idUsuario2 = $_REQUEST['idUsuario2']; 
    $gasto= $_REQUEST['gasto']; 
    $con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=bd", "root", "123"); 
    $res=false;
    $datos=array();
    if($wsSolicitado == 'wsuno'){
       $res=$con->query("SELECT idequivalente2,alimento,cantidad, unidad, peso, calorias FROM bdapp.tbalimentos where dequivalente2='$idequivalente'"); 
       $datos['alimentos']=$res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }else if($wsSolicitado == 'wsdos'){
       $res=$con->query("SELECT * FROM dieta WHERE idUsuario2='$idUsuario2' AND gasto='$gasto'");
       $datos['dieta']=$res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    }  
    echo json_encode($datos);
```

Algunas notas adicionales que están fuera de scope de esta pregunta:
1) Usa $_POST o $_GET en lugar de $_REQUEST
2) Para los WS y en especial cuando mandas usuario y/o clave utiliza $_POST (y https).
3) No uses sql dinámico. Usa prepared statements.
4) Sanitiza y valida los parametros recibidos (en $_POST, $_GET, $_REQUEST, etc) en php antes de usarlos.

Comment: Ahora estoy haciendo un web service. En este momento mando hago las dos consultas en un php con el metodo GET y paso estos parametros en la url=("http://192.168.1.34:8000/ServicioWeb/Menu.php?idequivalente2="+Integer.toString(verduras.getId())+"idUsuario2="+4000+"gasto="+1393.32); el codigo de php es este:

Comment: <?php
     $idequivalente = $_REQUEST['idequivalente2'];
   $idUsuario2 = $_REQUEST['idUsuario2'];
    $gasto= $_REQUEST['gasto'];

Comment: Angelica por favor actualiza la pregunta en lugar de escribir en los comentarios.

Comment: cuando ejecute la app ya no me muestra  ningun dato en la app no se si es por el php o el codigo en android

Comment: listo ya esta actualizada

Comment: La pregunta está mal formateada, el código está ingresado como párrafo de texto. Es muy dificil seguir la pregunta así. Hasta donde pude entender, no veo la diferencia con la pregunta anterior, por lo tanto entiendo que la duda es la misma, y vale la misma respuesta.

Comment: listo, espero se entienda mejor

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: para wsuno los parametros de la consulta se los paso asi: www.tusitio.com/webservice.php?ws=wsuno&idUsuario2=4000&gasto=1441.92&idequivalente2=20
 y para wsdos www.tusitio.com/webservice.php?ws=wsdos&idUsuario2=4000&gasto=1441.92&idequivalente2=20

Comment: Si. Eso resuelve tu pregunta. Despues fijate mis comentarios porque el código en general presenta varios temas de seguridad.

Comment: Muy bien estoy revisando los temas de seguridad, ahora la duda es donde pondria el codigo que obtiene el json de la consulta  en android